# power shell + how to capture the names in file before separator to variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

in file.info we have the following structure

```
kdme:424324
fejwde:3425
kededmrf:132456
edkmedefrf:45
.
.
.
```

how to set the variable - param with all names -  kdme fejwde kededmr edkmedefrf

expected output

```
echo $param

kdme fejwde kededmr edkmedefrf   . . .
```

note we are use powershell 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file.info include the first fields and separator and the second field

```
 Get-Content file.info | %{ $_.Split(':')[0]; }
```

Comment: Get-content file.info

Comment: yes , I am using Get-Content